# Agglomerative with even sized clusters

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Is there a way to make Agglomerative clustering in sklearn create even sized clusters?
I see that there's a [connectivity](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering.html#sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering) optional parameter, but not sure how to use it and if it helps.

Thanks,
Miki

Comment: And how would this agglomeration strategy work then? In any case the Ward clustering in scikit learn does not support this.

Comment: Thanks @eickenberg Is there a hierarchical clustering I can use which creates even sized clusters?

Comment: Again: What would the criterion for this clustering be?

Comment: @eickenberg What do you mean by "criterion"? Distance?

Comment: If you can formulate a precise rule how this clustering should be done, you can probably code it quite easily from that.